# Oracle-lost rpc connection to heterogeneous remote agent using sid

Tags: oracle, dblink

Im trying to select in plsql using dblink connected to mysql.

Here is my query:

```
 select
                t1."header_id" header_id
            from
                "table1"@times t1
                ,"table2"@times t2

            where
                t1."processed" = 'no'
                and 
                t1."returned" = 'yes'  
                and
                t2."header_id" is null  
                and
                t1."header_id" = t2."header_id"(+)
  ;
```

This is the error:

[image]

Please help.Thank you.

Comment: Did dblink work before this error? Or is it a mistake after creating a new dblink?

Comment: Yes its working. I tried to Select from single table **Select * from "table1"@times** and it works. But when I tried joining tables like the code above, I got an error.

Comment: Try to create a view in mysql and join table in mysql, and create sql for view. `t1."header_id" = t2."header_id"(+)` this is syntax oracle, not mysql.

Comment: I got your point. But that is not I want to do. I dont want to use a mysql view. I just need to run the query above.

Comment: Try this SQL `select
                t1."header_id" header_id
            from
                "table1"@times t1
 LEFT outer  JOIN "table2"@times t2
    ON  (t1."header_id" = t2."header_id")
            where
                t1."processed" = 'no'
                and 
                t1."returned" = 'yes'  
                and
                t2."header_id" is null  ;
`

Comment: I tried.But still I got the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184069/discussion-between-ktaro-and-dmitry-demin).